# How to handle polymorphism with interfaces in bounded type parameters? (Java)

Tags: java, oop, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

I've got a class hierarchy of the following kind:

```
class Declarations {

    interface Function<I, O> {
        interface BinaryFunction<I> extends Function<I, Boolean> {}
    }

    static abstract class FunctionImpl<I, O> implements Function<I, O> {

        static class BinaryFunctionImpl<I>
               extends FunctionImpl<I, Boolean>
               implements Function.BinaryFunction<I> {}
    }

    interface Optimizer<I, O, F extends Function<I, O>> {

        interface BinaryOptimizer<I>
        extends Optimizer<I, Boolean, Function.BinaryFunction<I>> {}
    }

    static abstract class AbstractOptimizer<I, O, F extends Function<I, O>>
                    implements Optimizer<I, O, F> {}

    static abstract class OptimizerImpl<I, O, F extends FunctionImpl<I, O>>
                    extends AbstractOptimizer<I, O, F> {

        static class BinaryOptimizerImpl<I>
               extends OptimizerImpl<I, Boolean, FunctionImpl.BinaryFunctionImpl<I>>
               implements BinaryOptimizer<I> {}
    }
}
```

The compiler stumbles upon the declaration of `BinaryOptimizerImpl<I>` and says:

> '`Optimizer`' cannot be inherited with different type arguments:
> '`BinaryFunctionImpl<I>`' and '`BinaryFunction<I>`'

But I don't understand the issue, as `BinaryFunctionImpl<I>` implements `BinaryFunction<I>` and both are passed the same parameter. So these two types should be compatible from my understanding. If `BinaryFunction<I>` was a class rather than an interface, I'd understand that constrained type parameters don't allow for instantiating them with subclasses unless declared with `? extends Type`. But for interfaces, this wouldn't make sense, as you can never instantiate an interface directly.

All of the shown types are already in active use within the surrounding codebase, except for `OptimizerImpl`/`BinaryOptimizerImpl`, which must provide the respective `Optimizer` interface. Also note that the inheritance from `AbstractOptimizer` in `OptimizerImpl` cannot be resolved by integrating it into `OptimizerImpl`, as it is also inherited from elsewhere (I know, the naming isn't ideal, sorry!).

How to make this compile with minimal impact on the existing class hierarchy, i.e. changing only the lowest-possible (most specific) type layer, to reduce the impact on the existing codebase? Is there a way to make this compile by only changing the declaration of `BinaryOptimizerImpl`? (Leaving away the obvious non-solution of not making it implement `BinaryOptimizer`)

I hope my question is comprehensible, I had to abstract a lot. I've done quite some research on the semantics of Generics in Java, but there's a large variety of mistakes to be made and I couldn't find any explanation for this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `F` in `Optimizer` cannot be both `BinaryFunctionImpl` and `BinaryFunction` at the same time, it must resolve to a single type.

What about

```
    interface BinaryOptimizer<I, G extends Function.BinaryFunction<I>>
            extends Optimizer<I, Boolean, G> {}

    static class BinaryOptimizerImpl<I>
            extends OptimizerImpl<I, Boolean, FunctionImpl.BinaryFunctionImpl<I>>
            implements BinaryOptimizer<I, FunctionImpl.BinaryFunctionImpl<I>> {}
```

Comment: That would be an elegant solution. But the issue with this is that ’BinaryOptimizer’ is a very essential type that is already used in dozens of places and I'd have to touch a large number of code files for adjustment. It would also make existing code more bloaty.

Comment: But your explanation made me realize why my current design isn't working. I was under the assumption that the types `BinaryFunction` and `BinaryFunctionImpl` wouldn't conflict, since the latter is a subtype of the first, which would've been enough to satisfy the type requirement of `BinaryOptimizer`. But then of course, the other way around, `BinaryFunction` couldn't satisfy the type requirement of `BinaryFunctionImpl` that I've set in `OptimizerImpl`. Only thinking from one side, I was blind to this mistake. I still don't have a good solution, but at least I've understood the problem better.

Comment: I found a solution (see my answer), but it's less clean and less general than your proposal. I've thus chosen to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that in my case, it is actually sufficient for `BinaryOptimizerImpl` to implement `Optimizer<I, Boolean, FunctionImpl.BinaryFunctionImpl<I>>`, which it already becomes through inheritance. Contrary to my initial assumption, its callers do not require it to be a `BinaryOptimizer`. Leaving away its declaration as `BinaryOptimizer` is the minimal-impact solution for my codebase.

However, leaving aside external complications and judging only from a design perspective, I do believe that the solution presented by upeterz is more clean with regards to the class hierarchy presented in my question, which is why I consider their answer as preferable.